# Can we make web app or website using flutter or Dart

Tags: dart, flutter, angular-dart

"I'm moving on to new language for creating cross platform app(flutter) but i am confused about creating web app or website , is it possible to make with Dart & flutter.

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-io/hummingbird-building-flutter-for-the-web-e687c2a023a8 is an experimental approach to run Flutter in the browser.

Comment: It will be released on 2019 by Google Hummingbird team. I am waiting it. Just look around React-TypeScript or Vue-TypeScript in temporary.

Answer (score 5):

As of May 8th, 2019, we can create web apps using Flutter. Read through this article for more info.

[Flutter: Create and Deploy a Website From Scratch](https://medium.com/@ayushshekhar/flutter-create-and-deploy-a-website-from-scratch-4a026ebd6c)

And the official git repository is [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web).

The readme in the git repository mentions setup, workflow, how to migrate from an existing codebase and much more.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

It is possible to write a web app using flutter as of June 2019. It's still in beta and is being worked on. It is [`flutter_web`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web).

It supports the flutter animations and has the same widget tree concept.

It's no longer the workflow to use just dart to write a web app.

### The answer below was applicable until a few months ago.

Long story short: everything you need is on Flutter website: https://flutter.io/ - Your question supposed to be "Can we make web app or website using Dart", Dart is a programming language, Flutter is using Dart to write mobile apps.

Comment: So cant we use flutter for write websites?

Comment: Obviously, it's for building mobile apps only

Comment: Yes, use AngularDart.  See dartlang.org.